# Custom Grid Filtering Expressions

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

Quick project background: I am porting some Telerik for ASP.NET grids/back end data sources to Kendo angular UI framework.

Problem: I'm trying to implement grid filtering (has to be custom since I manually bind to handle complex paging/data retrieval.

1. Is there any method/function to retrieve a filter string instead of the object model containing filters and operators? (I can, obviously, flatten this myself, but it's a bit of code). Here is a code snippet...

```js
if (filter !== undefined) {
            // Step through column filters
            filter.filters.forEach((element: any) => {
                // console.log(element);

                // Step through individual filter for column
                element.filters.forEach((curFilter: any) => {
                    console.log(curFilter.field);
                    console.log(curFilter.operator);
                    console.log(curFilter.value);
                });
            });
        }
```

2. I'm still using the dynamic linq queries that the .NET grid used for its filter expressions. Will the filter expressions that come out of grid.filters work correctly with a linq dynamic query on the back-end or will I need to convert?

I feel like I'm missing something here so I thought I'd start a conversation.

Thanks!
-Brian

Comment: Not sure I understand are you using DataSourceRequest of kendo.mvc assembly?

Comment: No. I'm binding asynchronously to an observable GridDataResult. That data is fetched from the server using a different API, etc... and the data is returned fine. Paging, sorting, and filtering are done on the server by the API... ie-> I have to manually sort, filter, etc.  Again, this is fine & a normal setup in many of the examples. For filtering, however, I need a string representation of the fitler to send to the server where the data is fetched & collected. In the .NET world of Telerik, this used a dynamic linq query string format.

Comment: Not 100% sure if its what you want but you can look at what I sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe based on your comment answer what you are attempting to do is get the filters and sorts, paging just like its sent for MVC on the network.

For kendo to do this you need to set your data source type and have the right file included in your page.

the file name is kendo.aspnetmvc.js or kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js

and your data source initialization should specify

```
dataSource: {
   transport: {
      type: 'aspnetmvc-ajax'
   }
}
```

or do the same thing are they are doing

the cdn for this script is https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js

I know they use the like of this functions to do what you are talking about

```
function serializeFilter(filter, encode) {
            if (filter.filters) {
                return $.map(filter.filters, function (f) {
                    var hasChildren = f.filters && f.filters.length > 1, result = serializeFilter(f, encode);
                    if (result && hasChildren) {
                        result = '(' + result + ')';
                    }
                    return result;
                }).join('~' + filter.logic + '~');
            }
            if (filter.field) {
                return filter.field + '~' + filter.operator + '~' + encodeFilterValue(filter.value, encode);
            } else {
                return undefined;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hmm... that might help me out, but I'm looking to do this in Angular, not .net mvc. I have the sorting and paging working fine... it's just the filters that were recently added that I can't quite figure out. The method above to serialize might help me though... it's similar to what I was doing manually above. But in the case of the ASP.NET implementations, this was spelled out more clearly by Telerik/Progress.

Comment: question would be what stops you from just sending the whole filter as is and on the server side having a model that represent the filter object structure of kendo?

Comment: Well, nothing really... if that is the approach I have to take. : )   But then I'd also have to translate the kendo filter object structure into a LINQ expression... which, again, I can do if this is the best / most correct course of action. It just seemed more transparent in previous versions regarding what the expected use-cases were for server filtering.

Comment: Well if you want I actually created a project that takes care of creating expression dynamically you can take a look at it https://github.com/PoweredSoft/DynamicLinq

Comment: Thanks again. I ended up writing my own version of the filter serialization and it does work for my needs. I guess I was hoping their was an easier way, but that works perfectly fine. Thanks!

Comment: glad i could help :)

Comment: @BriDev Can you share with how you done this ...? i stuck on same issue

Comment: Which part, specifically?

Comment: @UmerZaman, yes... which part is hanging you up?

My approach was to create a client function that converts the kendo grid filter expression into a linq type expression that my server was already expecting (so I didn't have to modify my server code).

Comment: i need to pass through parameter

Comment: Well, in general you setup filtering by using setting the filterable, and filter properties on the grid. Filterable turns filtering on/off (two different types: menu and header I believe), and Filter binds to a State object (the same type that is used for sorting). The state object will contain the current filter expression. State.filter is a CompositeFilterDescription. 

My problem above was mostly about converting that filter expression into a LINQ style query expression, which I did with a custom client function before sending it to the server.